# Cannot pass value to parent component in React.Js

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm strugelling with that one.

I'm trying to build a calendar using react-calendar package. In one place of my app I need to have an access to the calendar month's value. I'm calling the components property onActiveDateChange which I found in docs of the component (react-calendar). It is indeed a callback so I'm trying to use it as my chance to extract month value and send it up to the parent component. But that does not work, not only the value is not changed as expected, but the calendar stops working. Do you know what is causing that? I've tried also with setting a state in the callback but the same results, value is not correct.

Here's my chunk of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import ChooseHour from './ChooseHour';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class Calendario extends Component {
    state = { showHours: false,}


    onChange = date => this.setState({ 
        date }, () => {
            const { chosenRoom } = this.props;
            const year = date.getFullYear();
            const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            const day = date.getDate();
            const fullDate = `${year}/${month}/${day}`;
            const roomAndDayObj = {fullDate, chosenRoom};
            this.props.sendRoomAndDay(roomAndDayObj); 
        }
    )

    onClickDay(e) {
        this.setState({ showHours: true });
    } 

    passActiveDate(activeDate) {
        const monthAfterPress = activeDate.getMonth() + 1;
        console.log(monthAfterPress);
// this is weird in my opinion, I can log it and it works as expected, 
// when I'm firing the next line the values are incorrect


        // this.props.activeMonthToPass(monthAfterPress); //this line makes a problem
    }

    render() { 
        const { booked } = this.props;
        return ( 
        <div>
            <div className="calendarsCont">
                <Calendar
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    onClickDay={(e) => this.onClickDay(e)}
                    onActiveDateChange={({ activeStartDate }) => this.passActiveDate(activeStartDate)}
                    value={this.state.date}
                    locale="pl-PL"
                    tileDisabled={({date, view }) => 
                    date.getDate()===15 && date.getMonth()===6 && date.getFullYear()===2018}
                />
            </div> 
            <div>
                {this.state.showHours ? 
                    <ChooseHour chosenDay={this.state.date} chosenRoom={this.props.chosenRoom}/> : 
                null}
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}


export default connect (null, actions)(Calendario);
```

Comment: why do you need both `onChange` and `onActiveDateChange` ? why not just use `onChange`?

Comment: Hi @azium, because I need to have an access before user clicks the day tile. OnSumbit works after clicking.

Comment: ok well its still not clear what the issue is.. are you saying that `this.props.activeMonthToPass(..)` is what's breaking it? without that function call things still work?

Comment: this.props.activeMonthToPass(monthAfterPress) breaks the code, ie. the month is not changing, the same problem can be reproduced with this.setState({x: monthAfterPress}) instead of line above. But...console.log(monthAterPress) works like a charm (I can see months changing)

Comment: do you get any errors in the console when it breaks? calling `setState` should not break anything out of the blue like that

Comment: No, it is weird indeed. No errors, just calendar stucks on the same month, and the value is still the same